# Refresh or rebuild a RowsFragment class

Tags: android, android-fragments

How to refresh or rebuild a class that is extended from `RowsFragment`?
I have tried a few codes:

```
RowsFragment frg = this;
frg.getFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
ft.detach(frg);
ft.attach(frg);
ft.commit();
```

or

```
FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
ft.detach(this).attach(this).commit();
```

but still nothing.

Comment: Frankly I don't understand what are you trying to do.

Comment: @Rohit5k2 rebuild a fragment

Comment: You are simply using same instance while reattaching the fragment. Try my answer..

Answer (score 0):

You are simply using same instance while reattaching the fragment.

Create new instance of the fragment and replace it with existing one.

```
RowsFragment fragment = new RowsFragment();
FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();    
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container, fragment); // use your container in the place of R.id.container
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```